# Set Onclick on many views Android

Tags: android, onclick, case

I have a serie of ImageViews on my Activity. And I wanna execute a method when one of these is touched. I have the next:

```
  public void onClick(View v) {

          switch(v.getId()){

          case R.id.image1:
              mymethod(1,1,movimientos,(ImageView)v);
              break;
          case R.id.image2:
              ponerficha(1,2,movimientos,(ImageView)v);
              break;
          case R.id.image3:
...
```

But the method isn't executed, The problem not is the method, because any code in the cases not work. Any idea?

Comment: Have you `implements onClickListener`? And set the OnClickListener to the images view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing what you need to check if you already register `onClickListener` for your `Images`

```
image.setOnClickListener(this);
```

(This you have to use if your class implements OnClickListener interface)

Then how you declare and initialize your `ImageViews`, whether have own ids.

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.someId)
anotherImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.anotherId)
...
```

You can work with `onClickListeners` like with anonyme classes like

```
image.setOnClickListener(
   new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
         // some actions
      }
});
```

but more complex and better in the case you have many widgets to set implement `OnClickListener`.

```
public class ClassName extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {}
```

Comment: Thanks, I forget the image.setOnclickListener(this)!! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, your activity has to implement View.OnClickListener like so

```
public class myActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

Then you need to set your on click listener for your ImageViews. If all your ImageViews are in a linearlayout then the code would look like this

```
LinearLayout llImageViewHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llImageViewHolder);
for (int i = 0; i < llImageViewHolder.getChildCount(); i++ {
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) llImageViewHolder.getChildAt(i);
    iv.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an onClick handler to each view you are interested in processing clicks for.

How you do it depends on how you want to process the click events. You can either use hawaii.five-0's approach and have one event handler for everything, or you can have one event handler per view item which you could add in the onCreate method of your activity:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```